# visual studio code not recognized parcel

Tags: parceljs

hey guys i new to parcel and i am trying to use parcel to build my website on it. i installed parcel using

```
npm install --save-dev parcel
```

but didnt work. then i ran parcel index.html and it returns

```
parcel : The term 'parcel' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,  
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

i tried uninstalling parcel and reinstalling but didnt work. Any ideas why this happens? thank you in advance.
below is my package.json

package.json

```
 {
      "dependencies": {
        "dat.gui": "^0.7.7",
        "gsap": "^3.6.0",
        "load-asset": "^1.2.0",
        "nice-color-palettes": "^3.0.0",
        "three": "^0.126.1",
        "vec2": "^1.6.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "glslify-bundle": "^5.1.1",
        "glslify-deps": "^1.3.2",
        "parcel": "^2.0.1",
        "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.5"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `npm install --save-dev parcel`, you are installing *local* packages that are only intended to be used in this particular project, not everywhere on your computer (see [docs](https://nodejs.dev/learn/npm-global-or-local-packages)). So commands associated with those packages aren't added to your CLI's global path by default. One way to run locally installed commands is to put them your `package.json`'s `"scripts"` field:

```
{
   ...
   "scripts": {
      "build": "parcel index.html"
   }
}
```

When they are run in that context, they'll have access to the locally installed packages.

I noticed another problem with your `package.json` - you have both `parcel-bundler` *and* `parcel` packages installed. `parcel-bundler` is the deprecated v1 version of parcel, and when it's installed side-by-side with the `parcel` (v2) package, it will override the parcel command in your `scripts`, so you'll be getting v1 instead of v2, which is probably not what you want. I'd recommend running `npm uninstall parcel-bundler`.